# растягивание flex блоков относительно соседних

Tags: html, css

3 вертикальных блока, с растягивающимися по высоте центральной частью

```css
  .tree {display: flex; height: auto;}
  .tree > div {display: flex; flex-direction: column; width: 100%; border:1px solid red;}
  .tree > div > div {border:1px solid orange;}
  .tree > div > div:nth-child(1) {flex: 0 1 30px;}
  .tree > div > div:nth-child(2) {flex: 1 1 auto;}
  .tree > div > div:nth-child(3) {flex: 0 1 30px;}
```

```html
<div class="tree">
  <div>
    <div>Text</div><div>Text</div><div>Text</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Text</div><div>One Line<br />Two Line</div><div>Text</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div>Text</div><div>Text</div><div>Text</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

есть 3 блока, расположены вертикально. внутри каждого блока есть верхняя, средняя и нижняя часть. если в среднюю часть вписать много текста ( я вписал 2 строки ) то, кроме самого блока растянувшегося в высоту, растягиваются соседние блоки

подскажите, как можно изменить код таким образом, что бы верхние и нижние части так же тянулись, вместе с соседними? у меня в верстке ограничение на высоту 30px, вот хочется сделать высоту по контенту, как средний блок ( средний по высоте )

Comment: Если честно, не понятно. Можно подробнее описать проблему?

Comment: На данном форуме, есть фрагмент кода, его можно найти либо на панели редактирования (над полем ввода) либо нажать `CTRL + M`.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь `display: grid`, для сеток это лучшее решение.

Comment: @OliverPatterson это НЕ форум

Comment: @PeterKolosov, всегда было интересно, как правильно назвать?)

Comment: @OliverPatterson Сайт Q&A

Comment: @Maneken - представьте что на странице есть 3 товара, которые предлагаются пользователю. у каждого товара есть 3 блока (Шапка/Описание/Подвал). Вот в текущем примере, если я меняю описание, то все 3 блока по высоте нормально тянутся вертикально. А для Шапки и подвала - не понимаю как сделать аналогичное растягивание ( что бы соседние растягивались относительно размера самого большого, как блок с Описанием ) . Сейчас Гуглю про все решения с grid, но пока не нагуглил )

Comment: как вариант сделать отдельные блоги горизонтальные, а не вертикальные, тогда они будут тянуться все вместе по горизонту